# Loop through list of names and copy file explained?

Tags: bash, shell, loops

I've written a script to copy a new user account file to the new user location. It works by reading a list of usernames and copying the file to that location. I can't understand why I needed the `done < $USER` at the end. Can someone please explain this?

Thanks

```
USER=/home/example/new.txt
NEWUSER=$USER

LOC=/var/account/          

cd /home/example

while read NEWUSER
do
cp _newuser.txt $LOC/$NEWUSER
done < $USER
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To iterate over each line in the file `/home/example/new.txt`, which is the value of variable `USER`

Pls look at http://en.kioskea.net/faq/1757-how-to-read-a-file-line-by-line

`<` is `input redirection` operator (http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html)

You can also delete `NEWUSER=$USER`, since I do not see any use of `NEWUSER` except the `while` loop. Due to the `while`, `NEWUSER` will be assigned a new value each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Because read reads the input from standard input (stdin). In order to read from file you need to redirect it to the read command.